# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).cropper is not a function - cropper.js

Tags: javascript, cropperjs, cropper

I tried the tutorial at this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lrwLc-5UXs)

My code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
<link href="cropper.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<img id="teh" src="image.png" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="cropper.js"></script>
<script>        
    $("#teh").cropper();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But, it hits error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).cropper is not a function` at `$("#teh").cropper();`

Comment: https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/issues/707 and  https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/issues/85

Comment: Do you have the copper.js with your files? If yes, what's the path?

Comment: yes, i have copper.js

Comment: Could you verify the path where you have kept the copper.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution already. I need to add

```
<script src="jquery-cropper.js"></script>
```

so, it becomes

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="cropper.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-cropper.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using jQuery new version while it is supporting old version.

```js
var image = document.getElementById('image');
var cropper = new Cropper(image, {
  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
  crop: function(e) {
    console.log(e.detail.x);
    console.log(e.detail.y);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/0.8.0/cropper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/0.8.0/cropper.min.js"></script>

<img id="image" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-_nU33sjf1SI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAASgQ/VOkKnOIxP8g/photo.jpg?sz=328" />
```